# Time taken for a bead to slide down a wire.

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

A circular hoop of radius $r$ is stood vertically on a flat surface and held in place. A smooth wire is tightly stretched between the upmost point of the hoop and a point on the hoop at height $h$. A bead of mass $m$ is held at rest at the top of this wire, upon which it is threaded. When the bead is released, how long does it take to reach the bottom of the wire? Ignore air resistance. Give your answer in terms of $g$, $h$, $m$, and $r$.

A picture of the arrangement is shown below:

[image]

Here's a picture of my working:
[image]

I'll summarise the steps for clarity. First, I calculated the distance which the bead will travel in terms of $h$ and $r$, using some Pythagoras. Then, I calculated $cos(θ)$ in terms of $h$ and $r$ so that I could then resolve the acceleration $g$ into the component parallel to the wire, $gcos(θ)$. Finally, I applied the SUVAT equation $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ and did some rearrangement to get an expression for $t$.

However, this answer is incorrect but I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: I haven't checked it, but I always find "this answer is incorrect" to be an odd statement by the person asking the question.  How did you determine it's incorrect?  Is it a textbook problem and you're checking against an answer key? (if so, it would be helpful to give the textbook reference and page number)  Is it a graded problem and the grader just marked through it without any feedback?  Or perhaps it's a multiple choice question and none of the answers match your expression? (if so, it would be helpful to see the candidate answers)

Comment: You state _"Ignore air resistance."_ but you ignore **all** resistance.

Comment: @m-stgt What would be the source of resistance?  It's on a smooth wire, so friction isn't considered.  Do you want to propose magnetic resistance?

Comment: @BrianMoehring -- If a smooth wire or a lubed wire, I don't mind. For me the statement _"Ignore air resistance."_ implies, **do not** ignore other resistance like friction.

Comment: Won't the bead just remain at the top of the circle, since it has no idea whether to go left or right.

Comment: @DanAsimov The bead is on the chordal wire, not the circle. (the circle just makes the geometry of the wire a bit more complicated and otherwise can be ignored)

Comment: So the problem has nothing at all to do with the circle, does it?

Comment: @BrianMoehring This question is taken from a website called Isaac Physics. You can basically submit an answer and it will tell you whether it is correct or not, with no explanation.

Comment: @DanAsimov Correct, the circle can effectively be ignored.

Comment: @m-stgt The question intends for friction to be ignored, hence describing the wire as smooth

Comment: @BrianMoehring If $\theta$ is the angle between the wire an the vertical axis, the tangential force in the wire is given by $mg\cos\theta$ If $d$ is the wire extent, then $d = \frac 12 m g\cos\theta t^2$

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. Where did $m$ come from? I thought the acceleration due to gravity is $g$, so this needs to be resolved in the direction parallel to the wire to get the acceleration of the bead, giving $gcosθ$, not $mgcosθ$? What I mean is, why do we need to consider the force if we are applying a SUVAT equation?

Comment: @Developer Yes you are right. Mass doesn't play anything in the equation. The correct is: $d=\frac 12g\cos\theta t^2$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky I like investigating strange statements given without context such as "this answer is incorrect."  I eventually found that particular problem on the website you mentioned and played with it long enough to find the issue.

In short, your answer is correct...

... but it's not simplified enough for that website to accept it.  Specifically,

$$\frac{8r^2-4hr}{2gr-gh} = \frac{4r(2r-h)}{g(2r-h)} = \frac{4r}{g}$$
as long as $2r \neq h$ (if $h=2r$, then the question itself has problems, so I think it's safe to ignore that case)

That is, your answer is equivalent to $\sqrt{4r/g}$, which is accepted.

*Is anything surprising about that answer?  Where is the $h$?*

That said, you do have one error in your work, even though it didn't end up mattering. You have assumed, in your diagram, that $h \leq r$.  To be complete, you'd need to also show it works for $r < h < 2r$.

---

And as a follow-up question: Suppose we have infinitely many smooth wires intersecting at a point and making a plane which is not orthogonal to the gravity vector.  Each wire has its own bead, all of which start at the intersection point.

All the beads are released at the same time and allowed to travel for $t$ seconds.  Describe the shape formed by the beads at this time.